# Cython in Win64 with TDM-GCC reports "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 1: invalid start byte"

Tags: python, gcc, cython

I am using Cython 0.20.1 with Python 3.3 in 64 bit Windows 7, with latest TDM-GCC installed (it's only a problem with gcc... MSVC does not report this).

Here is the `test_cy.pyx` file:

```
import numpy as np

cpdef func():
    cdef double [:] a = np.arange(10)
    return a
```

And then, I used this `setup_test.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

extensions = [
    Extension('test_cy', ['test_cy.pyx'], include_dirs = [np.get_include()]),
    ]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
    )
```

In the command console, I used:

```
python setup_test.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32
```

And it compiled fine. However, when I tried to import the module in python using `import test_cy`, it says:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-533d835504db> in <module>()
----> 1 import test_cy

X:\WorkFolder\DataAnalysis\lw9pg\mol\stringsource in init test_cy (test_cy.c:13209)()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce this on Linux with default GCC compiler. Also, you should specify exact versions of Python and Cython.

Comment: @Veedrac Thanks! I guess it's specific to TDM-GCC on Windows. By the way, my Python and Cython version are listed in the beginning... What do you mean by "exact"? Could you name an example?

Comment: Nope; I'm just blind.