# Cython not working with memoryviews in Anaconda3 64bit on Win 7

Tags: python, gcc, numpy, cython, anaconda

Edit: explanation on why I do not think it is a duplicate for [Cython in Win64 with TDM-GCC reports "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 1: invalid start byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210563/cython-in-win64-with-tdm-gcc-reports-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x83-in-po)

This question is for Anaconda3, which should be the largest scientific python distribution, so I think it should definitely work with cython and memoryview out of the box.

The old question is that I custom put tdm-gcc and python together, so there's definitely chance that I am responsible for that to be not working.

Overall, these two questions may not be the same root, and addresses completely to different users.

---

Note: co-listed in Cython mailing list and Anaconda mailing list. Sorry to spam subscribers of both lists.

Dear all,

I was kinda shocked that Anaconda 3 is having this issue (both `cython` and `memoryview` are really commonly used). Was I doing anything wrong?

Environment: Windows 7, Anaconda 3 (default setup with `conda install mingw`, 64 bit, Python 3.4 64 bit

```
# test_memory_view.pyx
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cpdef double [:] func():
    cdef double [:] a = np.arange(10.)
    return a



# test_compiler_script.py
import numpy as np
import pyximport
pyximport.install(setup_args={'script_args':['--compiler=mingw32'],
                              'include_dirs':np.get_include()},
                  reload_support=True)
import test_memory_view
```

And it would not run, since it'll say `"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 1: invalid start byte"`

The code would run correctly if I use WinPython because it is using another version of gcc (mingw-w64 numpy static toolchain by Carl Kleffner).

Could anyone please confirm? Thanks!

Shawn

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cython in Win64 with TDM-GCC reports "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 1: invalid start byte"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210563/cython-in-win64-with-tdm-gcc-reports-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x83-in-po)

Comment: So to clarify: you're not using TDM-GCC but instead you're using the default version of the mingw gcc that comes with Anaconda? (I don't know the answer, but I imagine this information would be useful to someone who did know)

Comment: @DavidW Yes! Thanks for helping to clarify. My op was a little bit misleading. In short, I 1) installed Anaconda3 with everything default, and 2) used conda install mingw. That's it! I will modify the OP now to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some known issues with using the conda mingw and Cython (https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/271). You might try installing [mingw static](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/wiki/Mingw-static-toolchain) instead, or using Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you Aaron! You've always been so helpful. And yes - I used the mingw static toolchain and solved the problem. Also, thanks for the reference! I will report this issue to github for future reference.